# Hair particle edit mirror doesn't work

Tags: particles

I tried to x mirror my particle edit but it doesn't work.[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you just add random particles, they are all over the place, not mirrored, so the mirror function doesn't know what to do. You'll need to delete all particles in particle edit mode and use the add brush while symmetry is alread turned on. 
usually you would place a couple of hairs far apart, comb them and use interpolated mode on the add tool, so you have a running start.